# How to maintain the order of values while doing rollup in a spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I  do a rollup of the below dataframe ,i.e have only a single record for the common key and its values as a tuple and maintain the order of the values .

I am able to do the roll up but not able to maintain the order of values.

```
 +-------------
    |    key| val|
    +-------------
    |      A|4816|
    |      A|5732|
    |      A|5542|
    |      B|5814|
    |      B|5812|
    |      B|5499|
    |      C|5992|
    |      C|7299|
    |      C|5193|
```

Expected O/P

```
key | val
A   | (4816, 5732, 5542)
B   | (5814, 5812, 5499)
C   | (5992, 7299, 5193)
```

How can I maintain the order of values while doing the rollup?

Comment: You will have to generate a new column for ordering before you create a dataframe because dataframes are distributed and without ordering information, there is no way to preserve order.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is you don't. In general case `DataFrames` are *not ordered*, therefore there is nothing to preserve. Furthermore aggregations require shuffle, and as such, don't guarantee any processing order of operations.

In specific cases you can try something similar to:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df
  .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)
  .groupBy("key")
  .agg(collect_list(struct($"id", $"val")).alias("val"))
  .select($"key", sort_array($"val").getItem("val").alias("val"))
```

but use it at your own risk, and only if you fully understand guarantees of the upstream execution plan.